# Gnuplot transparent shaded area between curves

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data set with mean and standard deviation columns. I can plot mean+sigma and mean-sigma curves above and below the mean. Now I want light shading between the +-sigma but still see the mean curve. I've tried the below transparent setting but still no success.

```
 set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
 plot 'inter.dat' using 1:2 with linespoints lc "black", \
      'inter.dat' using 1:($2-$3)  with linespoints lc "blue", \
      'inter.dat' using 1:($2+$3)  with linespoints lc "blue", \
      'inter.dat' using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc "skyblue" fs solid 0.5
```

Sample data:

```
 0.490  -5.809   +2.203 
 0.500  -1.293   +1.370 
 0.520  -1.026   +0.979 
 0.530  -0.877   +0.961 
 0.540  -0.656   +0.937 
 0.550  -0.878   +0.923 
 0.560  -0.649   +0.876 
 0.570  -0.729   +0.859 
 0.580  -0.370   +0.771 
 0.590  -0.421   +0.710
```

Your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify `transparent` in your first fillstyle declaration, but essentially override that in the plot command. You can do either

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
plot 'inter.dat' using 1:2 with linespoints lc "black", \
     'inter.dat' using 1:($2-$3)  with linespoints lc "blue", \
     'inter.dat' using 1:($2+$3)  with linespoints lc "blue", \
     'inter.dat' using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc "skyblue"
```

or

```
plot 'inter.dat' using 1:2 with linespoints lc "black", \
     'inter.dat' using 1:($2-$3)  with linespoints lc "blue", \
     'inter.dat' using 1:($2+$3)  with linespoints lc "blue", \
     'inter.dat' using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc "skyblue" fs transparent solid 0.5
```

to get

[image]

Also, keep in mind that not all terminals support transparency; the above image was generated using `pngcairo`.

Comment: The output to pngcairo is OK. But the screen xterm looks bad with no transparency. Could be an issue with the xterm driver.

Comment: I don't think the `X` terminal supports transparency, but the interactive `wxt` and `qt` terminals do. If you are stuck with `X`, a workaround might be to draw the filled area first, and the line for the mean curve on top of it.